# How to "Revert to default" on all Power BI Visualizations in one operation?

Tags: powerbi

I have inherited a set of reports in Power BI and need to update and add to the existing pages. I want to apply a custom theme to all the visualizations for a consistent look. Some of the visualizations have been individually formatted using the Power BI Desktop and therefore the imported theme does not control the individual visualizations.

Is there a way to apply "Revert to default" as a single operation on ALL visualizations and their properties without having to drill through one by one?

Comment: Not that I've seen